# Name of an independent film whose making was documented by another film....Heart of Darkness kind-of-thing

Tags: identify-this-movie

The film and, I believe, the Documentary about the making of the film start with C.  Like Corvalis, or Cromanthus....

The documentary was shot up north in the US, maybe Wisconsin, Michigan.  It stars the filmmaker, and his family and friends (the stars of the actual film).  It is a strangely compelling documentary because the film maker has no money, no real obvious skill and no real tration with anyone in the community that might want to see him succeed except an Uncle and the one best friend, if memory serves.

There is tragically comic scene where the guy is documenting a segment in which a guy gets his head slammed through a cabinet (the actual movie) -- and it obviously is very painful, no stuntman, no evident re-engineering of the panneling to make it easier to put a head through, etc....the documentary keeps rolling as we see the actors and director come to an impass becuase the guy really hurt his head.

And in the end, the director (kind of a goofball, dyslexic type with lots of passion) gets to finsh the film because his uncle dies and leaves him 50k.  The documentary guy is very dissapointed that the director kept the original working title (the one I can't f'in remember...).

I can remember some other details but the two or three above are the most memorable. Think I saw this on Netflix streaming about 4 years ago when there was really no content.  Please help me.

Answer (score 18):

The documentary is "[American Movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181288/)", which depicts amateur filmmaker Mark Borchardt's attempt to produce a horror movie called "[Coven](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0225434/)".

Further reading:

- [American Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Movie)
- [Coven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coven_%28film%29)

Comment: Outstanding!!!!!!!!

Comment: @John If this was the correct answer to your question, then [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/162011) and up-voting is the correct response.